# How do we use a variable from one method to another for eg im trying divide one variable by another

Tags: java

I'm trying to divide variables from pointsearned and creditsearned method in the pointsaverage method but it gives "Your grade point average isNaN" when i run it , how do i fix this ?(I'm a beginner)

```
public class JavaApplication40 {
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
   double credits = 0;
   double Points = 0;
   double average = 0;

   IDnumber();
    CreditsEarned(credits);
    PointsEarned(Points);
    System.out.println("Your grade point average is" +  PointAverag(average, Points, credits));
}
public static void IDnumber(){
  String docNuMBER; 
    System.out.println("Enter your student ID number ");
    docNuMBER = keyboard.nextLine();

}

public static double CreditsEarned( double credits){
    double NumCreditsEarned;
    System.out.println("Enter your Credit hours earned");
    NumCreditsEarned = keyboard.nextDouble(); 
    return NumCreditsEarned;
}

public static double PointsEarned(double points){
   double NumberOpoints;
   System.out.println("Enter your credit points");
   NumberOpoints = keyboard.nextDouble();
   return NumberOpoints;
}
public static double PointAverag(double grade , double NumberOpoints ,
        double NumCreditsEarned) {
   double average ;
    average =   NumberOpoints/NumberOpoints;
    return average ;
```

Comment: Functions/methods typically start with a lowercase in java.

Comment: You probably want something like `double points = PointsEarned();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what's happening in your program:

You set 'credits' and 'points' to 0.
These two variables have not been modified when you get to pass them to 'pointAverag'

```
System.out.println("Your grade point average is" +  PointAverag(average, Points, credits));
```

this line, literally, does this:

```
System.out.println("Your grade point average is" +  PointAverag(0, 0, 0));
```

And eventually leads to:

```
average = 0/0
```

**in 'PointAverag' which is NAN when stored in a double.**

Watch out for this line:

```
average =   NumberOpoints/NumberOpoints;
```

it has logical mistake in it. It will always store either 1 or NAN.

As mentionned in the comments, you need to update those variables, 'credits' and 'points', by storing the returned value of your methods 'PointsEarned' and 'CreditsEarned' in them:

```
CreditsEarned(credits);
PointsEarned(Points);
```

Becomes

```
credits = CreditsEarned(credits);
points = PointsEarned(Points);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you ,it did help (sorry for the late reply)

Answer (score 1):

Write:

```
System.out.println("Your grade point average is" +  PointAverag(IDnumber(), PointsEarned(Points), CreditsEarned(credits)));
```

instead.

If you don't use a returned value, it gets discarded.